# How to save an image to phone memory Android

Tags: android

I have a Bitmap image I want to be able to save to the phone and have it show up in Mediascape.

Any ideas on how to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i'm pretty sure if you save the image to the sd card or something it'll automatically be detected by the photo app

for storing on the phone's memory read the docs on data storage [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) and set the mode to MODE_WORLD_READABLE so other apps can see the file